# How to create a child entity without first setting reference to parent using JPA Repositories

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

The JPA/Hibernate documentation is not clear to me why I must set reference to the parent object of a ManyToOne relationship when trying to add a child entity.

For example,

If I do a two-staged add like this:

Stage 1:

- Create new Parent
- flush

Stage 2 :

- Create new Child
- call `child.setParentId(parent.getParentId())` rather than `child.setParent(parent)`
- flush

Why do I get a Not Null Constraint violation for the foreign key reference to the parent even when setting the parentId on the child entity that I am saving? I want to be able to manage children by themselves; their existence has no affect on the parent.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? If so, what secret mixture of annotations do I need to combine together?

Here is some code to outline my issue:

**Parent.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parents")
public class Parent
{

    protected String parentId;

    protected Collection<Child> children;

    public Parent()
    {
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "parent_id", columnDefinition = "VARCHAR(42) NOT NULL", nullable = false, length = 42, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    public String getParentId()
    {
        return parentId;
    }

    public void setParentId(String parentId)
    {
        this.parentId = parentId;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    public Collection<Child> getChildren()
    {
        if(children == null){
            children = new LinkedList<>();
        }
        return children;
    }

    public void setCards(Collection<Child> children)
    {
        this.children = children;
    }

}
```

**Child.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="children")
public class Child
{

  protected String childId;

  protected Parent parent;

    @Id
    @Column(name="card_id", columnDefinition="VARCHAR(42) NOT NULL", length=42, nullable=false, insertable=true, updatable=false)
    public String getCardId()
    {
        return childId;
    }

    public void setCardId(String childId)
    {
        this.childId = childId;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", nullable = false, updatable=false)
    public Parent getCardholder()
    {
        return parent;
    }

    public void setParent(Parent parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have mentioned nullable=false in @JoinColumn(name="parent_id", nullable = false, updatable=false) in child entity that's why you are getting that error. try removing it and executing it again.

Comment: When I remove that constraint, the relationship is never added, besides, don't I want that field to be not null?

Comment: You yourself said in the question that existence of child entity is independent on parent. Then what is the point of making it non-nullable? In order to save Child entity independently upon parent, you have to set Parent_id as nullable otherwise database won't allow you to save the data in the table. Also. can you include the exact stack trace.

Comment: I think you may have interpreted it differently that I meant, I didn't say that the child entity is independent of the parent, I said the parent's existence is independent of the child, meaning that the parent can exist with 0 children.